# i want to make my jumbotron fill body and the tip of nav bar how do i that

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

[image: i want my jumbotron to fill the parent body and touch the tip of the nav barr]

theres my css please assist

```css
.jumbotron {
  padding-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background-image: url("img/h1.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well hard to tell with just that code. Put width:100% on your jumbotron and try to remove margins and padding on it. Then adjust the padding/margin-top to position it at the tip of your navbar.